# When logging into the Umbraco 5 back office using Chrome or IE, I get redirected back to the login page but Firefox is fine?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have got a new Umbraco 5 website up and running pretty much out of the box, having taken the code from CodePlex and run the installation routine. I can't seem to be able to login when using Chromr or IE but can with Firefox.

It does seem to accept my login details because it shows no errors, just loops back to showing the login page. If I type in nonsense credentials, it does then throw an "invalid login" error as I would expect it to.

This is the case with all browsers but Firefox, as when using FF it works totally fine and there are no further issues. So I can use FF if I really want to but prefer to use Chrome and my users will not expect to use one particular browser once the site is done.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

As strange as it sounds, make sure the server time is correct and in sync with your workstation. Perhaps make sure they both update from some time server automatically. I have had really strange things when the time is off.

it maybe that if the server time is a day early, it is logging you off immediately after you logon, thinking that there has been sufficient idle time since you have done anything.

Not sure why this might vary depending on the browser, but worth a check.

EDIT: I confirmed this is a problem. When I set my server time back one day, I could no longer log in with IE or Chrome.