# Cannot login to Umbraco 6.0.7 back office using Firefox and Chrome, I am redirected back to the login page but IE and Safari is fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco6

I seem to be coming across an issue with logging into the Umbraco cms backoffice. Each time after having entered the correct username and password, Umbraco redirects me back to the login page. This happens in my staging environment but works fine on all browsers in my local environment

The url on my address bar is as follows in my staging environment after the redirection:

> http://www.somewebsiteurl.com/umbraco/login.aspx?redir=%2fumbraco%2fumbraco.aspx

This gives me a 200 OK status.

I couldn't determine what the cause of this was, and so decided to come up with the following check list as a process of elimination.

So my scenario was as below:

- Does it work in other browsers? IE and Safari but not Chrome and FireFox
- Any messages in the log? No errors seen with authentication
  and authorization
- Page is reloaded without any errors? No
- Is the database down by any chance? No
- Any javascript errors? No
  http://www.somewebsiteurl.com/umbraco/login.aspx?redir=%2fumbraco%2fumbraco.aspx gives
  me a 200 OK. This happens for me on my staging environment.

My local environment works just perfectly fine.
I have tried to perform the following on the staging environment

1. Delete TEMP folder in App_Data and restart website in IIS
2. Replicate database from staging to my local environment
3. Restart website on IIS on staging and local
4. Compare differences between staging and local only client dependency.config is different.
5. Copy all of the website from staging to local including web.config (web.config
   points to staging database)
6. Ensure that date and time settings are
   identical between the two environments Although the language
   settings for the date and time clock was different. (This was referring to a post here, http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9587048/when-logging-into-the-umbraco-5-back-office-using-chrome-or-ie-i-get-redirected)

Based on all the steps above,

I can login normally without any redirection issues on all browsers in my local environment. However, the staging environment gives me this issue.

Staging environment - cannot login via Chrome and FF but IE and Safari works

Can anyone please help??

The version of Umbraco I am using is 6.0.7.

Comment: you should update your umbraco version, there are said to be flaws and security risks with the 6.0x versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly confusing, but can you check that:

- Your database connection in the staging web.config is correct; and
- the staging database's user/login has sufficient rights, and is assigned to the database

I know you say that Safari and IE work fine, but just to cover the basics it's worth checking the database connections first.

Comment: Digby,
I have to give this a try. I will let you know.

Comment: Hi Digby, I have verified what the issue is not the staging database. My database connection in the staging web.config is correct and so as the user/login rights were sufficient and assigned correctly to the appropriate database.

Comment: I realised that my colleague changed the region language to Hong Kong on the server (thus resulting in a Chinese language) and another colleague of mine then made an update to the datetime (via command prompt as he was testing an application) on the server which was incorrect and then later changed it back to the correct time. This was still not working after an auto windows time sync. Anyhow, we restarted the server and everything worked again. I realise that a restart is recommended after having changed the region and date/time to properly propagate through the sites.